# Height Percentage, responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ton of different `divs` on my website, I finally finished the width part, setting all kind of different calculated widths and percentage of their width.

Anyhow now I'm onto the height of the different `divs`, and I can't seem to get to use height percentage to work on the following div showed on this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpwoT.jpg

I want it to reach to the bottom and no further, so my website is fit for different browsers. If I set the `divs` height a predetermined like `height:500px` and it fits like a charm on Chrome, it won't fit like a charm in Firefox, or if I re-size the browser window. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Use `vh` or `%` instead of px

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: if you use flex, then it could work without to mind % values for the most. but what about content ? is it suppose to shrink/expand too ?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adRgGM